# Need help in Android with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

SignupActivity.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_signup.*

class SignupActivity:AppCompatActivity(){

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup)


    val signname =findViewById<EditText>(R.id.signNameTxt)
    val s=signname!!.text.toString()

    fun validate(){
        if(s.isNotEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Working :)",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Not Working :(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    signNxtBtn.setOnClickListener{
       validate()
    }
}
public override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
}
}
```

This is a simple code for signup activity to validate whether the field is empty or not for further processing

```
if(s.isNotEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Working :)",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Not Working :(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

In this part of the code, whether I enter any value inside the text field, the application is returning the else part.

Comment: `if (signname!!.text.isNotEmpty()) {...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading the edittext value too early. Move the

```
val s=signname!!.text.toString()
```

inside your `validate()` function.

Answer (score 0):

**

> Use your code like this.

**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val s = tvDisplay.text.toString()

        btnOk.setOnClickListener {
            validate(s)
        }
    }

    private fun validate(s:String) {

        if(s.isNotEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Working :)",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Not Working :(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    } }
```